# Neo4j OGM library with embedded server

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Is it possible to use the OGM library with one embedded server ? 
The examples I have seen so for the session is always obtain via remote http connection to the neo4j server.
I would like to have the elegant programming model of the ***OGM library without the having the make network IO to the database***.
Thank you, kindly
Oscar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current release of the OGM (1.1.4) supports only the Neo4j remote server. 
OGM 2.0 will provide support for Neo4j remote server (http) and embedded Neo4j. Once Neo4j 3.0 is released, OGM 2.x will support the new binary (Bolt) protocol as well.

The first milestone of OGM 2.0 is expected within the next two weeks.